# Identificar el mayor de 5 Parrafos (p)

Tags: javascript, array, caracteres

necesito de su ayuda lo antes posible, tengo un ejercicio que consiste en identificar el "numero de caracteres" de 5 parrafos y determinar cual es el parrafo que posee la mayor cantidad de letras a traves de un Alert (); 
Logre determinar el numero de letras de cada parrafo y compararlos, asi como mostrar mediante el Alert(); la mayor cantidad de letras, PERO, no logro mostrar CUAL es el parrafo, es decir, si el I, II, III, IV o V. Agradeceria su ayuda,adjunto mi codigo.

```
    function identificar () {
    let parrafo = document.querySelector('#parrafo').innerHTML.length;
    alert ('El tamaño del parrafo I es de ' + parrafo + ' caracteres'); 
    let parrafo2 = document.querySelector('#parrafo2').innerHTML.length;
    alert ('El tamaño del parrafo II es de ' + parrafo2 + ' caracteres');
    let parrafo3 = document.querySelector('#parrafo3').innerHTML.length;
    alert ('El tamaño del parrafo III es de ' + parrafo3 + ' caracteres'); 
    let parrafo4 = document.querySelector('#parrafo4').innerHTML.length;
    alert ('El tamaño del parrafo IV es de ' + parrafo4 + ' caracteres');
    let parrafo5 = document.querySelector('#parrafo5').innerHTML.length;
    alert ('El tamaño del parrafo V es de ' + parrafo5 + ' caracteres');

    let comparar = [parrafo, parrafo2,parrafo3,parrafo4,parrafo5];

    let Parrafomayor = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < comparar.length; i++) {
            if (comparar[i] > Parrafomayor) {

            Parrafomayor = comparar[i];

    }
}
   alert ('El Parrafo con mayor cantidad de caracteres es el número: ' + Parrafomayor);

}
```

ME MUESTRA LA CANTIDAD DE LETRAS DEL PARRAFO, pero no me dice cual es el Parrafo.

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenid@, morsa.

Creo que a tu código sólo le falta agregar una variable que guarde el número del párrafo cuando determine que es el de mayor cantidad de caracteres, proceso que ya lograste al parecer con tu ciclo. En tu ejemplo, sería algo como:

```
    let Parrafomayor = 0;
    let PosicionParrafomayor = 0; // aqui ira el indicador del parrafo

    for (i = 0; i < comparar.length; i++) {
        if (comparar[i] > Parrafomayor) {

        Parrafomayor = comparar[i];
        PosicionParrafomayor = i + 1; // Ya que la posición en el mundo real parte en 1, no en cero como ocurre en el array
      }
   }
```

Y luego en tu mensaje de salida:

`alert ('El Parrafo con mayor cantidad de caracteres es el número: ' + PosicionParrafomayor);`

Comment: Muchas gracias quinqui me funciono. Mil gracias!.

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
//seleccionamos los elementos de la etiqueta p que su id empieze con parrafo
parrafos = document.querySelectorAll("p[id^='parrafo']");

   //creamos un arreglo para el mayor y el parrafo especifico!
   mayor = [0,0];
  //hacemos un loops
for (var i = parrafos.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
// si es mayor al anterior agrega el parrafo a la posicion 1 y en la 0 la cantidad de letras
  if (parrafos[i].innerHTML.length > mayor[0]) {
      mayor[0] = parrafos[i].innerHTML.length;
      mayor[1] = parrafos[i]; 
  }
}
alert(`el parrafo mas lago es el ${mayor[1].id} con ${mayor[1].innerHTML.length} caracteres`);
```

```html
<p id="parrafo1">hola</p>
<p id="parrafo2">hola1</p>
<p id="parrafo3">hola22</p>
<p id="parrafo4">hola333</p>
<p id="parrafo5">hola4444</p>
<p id="parrafo6">hola55555</p>
<p id="parrafo7">hola666666</p>
```

>

Comment: Gracias bryro, buen codigo, tambien funciona. Mil gracias.